# How to use a Python list comprehension with a conditional expression

Tags: python, list-comprehension, conditional-statements

There is a dict,

```
dlist = [{'Bilbo' : 'Ian', 'Frodo' : 'Elijah'}, {'Bilbo' : 'Martin', 'Thorin' : 'Richard'}]
```

And let `k = 'Frodo'`

I want to extract the value corresponding to k when it exists and make a list.

I wrote

```
value_list = [dlist[i][k] for i in range(len(dlist)) if k in dlist[i] else "NOT PRESENT"].
```

But computer says `else` is wrong. I don't know why.

Comment: Try this - `[dlist[i][k] if k in dlist[i] else "NOT PRESENT" for i in range(len(dlist)) ].`

Comment: Actually, there are two dicts in a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` after the `for` in a list comprehension is for filtering the list: when the condition is false you get no element at all.

`if..else` before the list comprehension is simply a ternary operator, no different than in any other expression.

A couple of other points: `for i in range(len(...))` is almost always wrong in Python. If you are only iterating over a single list just iterate over that.
Also, dictionaries have a method `.get()` that you can use to avoid the `if` altogether. So:

```
value_list = [d.get(k, "NOT PRESENT") for d in dlist]
```

or if you prefer the `if`:

```
value_list = [d[k] if k in d else "NOT PRESENT" for d in dlist]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But why is "for i in range(len(...))" wrong for iterating a single list in python? and what is the meaning of "iterate over that"?

Comment: @JihoBaek They meant that you can rewrite `dlist[i][k] for i in range(len(dlist))` to just be `d[k] for d in dlist`, since `d` will refer to each element of the list as it iterates, rather than using `i` as an index.

Answer (score 7):

When you have `else` part in the list comprehension , bring it before the for loop , Example -

```
value_list = [dlist[i][k] if k in dlist[i] else "NOT PRESENT" for i in range(len(dlist))]
value_list
>>> ['Elijah', 'NOT PRESENT']
```